# iPhone Documents Folder how to move/copy from host to iphone?. confusing

Tags: iphone, macos, xcode4, itunes

1) I have a sqlite database .db in the host machine ie: mac. say: sample.db

2) I have a iPhone application which looks this sample.db in the Documents Folder.

3) I have a itune version of 10.6.3. Mac: Lion OS.

I just want to copy this sample.db to iPhone Documents Folder. How to do this?

Comment: in itunes when you connect device which has your app your app will appear in itunes left side. there you can see documents and import the db to app's documents folder. But first you need to do what CodeBrickie is saying. You must have source code or tell your developer to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable iTunes document sharing for your app first.

To do this, set `UIFileSharingEnabled` to `YES` in your `Info.plist`. After running your app on the iOS device for the first time with this configuration option enabled, you will see the app in the iTunes file sharing view when the device is plugged in.

You can now drag & drop your file onto the file sharing view in iTunes and it gets synced to the iOS device.

Answer (score 2):

For sharing file to iPhone app you need to eneble the `UIFileSharingEnabled` key in your `info.plist` file.

[image: File sharing]

When syncing your device with iTunes, select your app. You will see a window like:

[image: ITunes sharing]

Click the add button and add your db file and sync.